# text justify is not working correctly with RichText

Tags: dart, flutter, richtext

I am using `RichText` and in this
text justify is not working correctly with `RichText` when using any of text span with style `decoration: TextDecoration.underline`

```
RichText(
          softWrap: true,
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          text: TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
            children: getSpan(),
          ),
        )
```

```
List<TextSpan> getSpan() {
    List<TextSpan> spans = List<TextSpan>();
    spans.add(TextSpan(
      text:
      "And thus We made them rise ",
    ));
    spans.add(
      TextSpan(
          text: " they ",
          style: TextStyle(
             decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
          ),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () {
              print("click on me");
            }),
    );
    spans.add(TextSpan(
      text:
      " And thus We made them rise ",
    ));
    return spans;
  }
```

[image: See the restul]

Comment: I think you can report this bug on Github

Comment: I've submitted on [flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28891)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a nasty effect of `textAlign` property when set to `TextAlign.justify`.

```
RichText(
          softWrap: true,
          //textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          text: TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
            children: getSpan(),
          ),
        )
```

**Updated to 21/03/19**

The [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28891) it is now fixed and at the moment (21/03/19) it is available in the master flutter channel:

```
flutter channel master
```

Comment: What if the text justification is needed here, how do we make. It happen?